# Javascript check new results in database

Tags: javascript, php

I’m working on a Javascript function for checking database updates and the first part, checking for updates, is working *(the javascript sends a post request to a php-file and then shows the result if there's any).*

The user gets a notification in the `nav-bar` when something has happened.

**Problem**: If the user checks the news, it's still news and the nav-bar is showing the same notification even if the user already has seen it.

Instead, the `JS` should only search for new results.

What is the correct approach for this?

HTML:

```
<li><a href="home?show=my_turn">My turn <span id="my_turn_news" class="badge" style="display: none;">0</span></a>/li>
```

Php:

```
if ($_POST['check'] == 'my_turn') {
    $my_turn = sqlSelect("SELECT DISTINCT(story_writers.story_id) FROM `story_writers` INNER JOIN story WHERE story_writers.user_id = {$_POST['user_id']} AND story_writers.on_turn = 1 AND story.total_rows < story.max_rows;");

    if (count($my_turn) > 0)
        echo count($my_turn);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var overview_news = document.getElementById('overview_news');
var my_turn_news = document.getElementById('my_turn_news');

setInterval(function checkMyTurn() {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText > 0) {
                if (overview_news.style.display == 'none' && my_turn_news.style.display == 'none') {
                    overview_news.style.display = 'inline';
                    my_turn_news.style.display = 'inline';
                }

                my_turn_news.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'functions/search.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('check=my_turn&user_id=<?=$_SESSION['user_id']; ?>'); 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: `if (isset($my_turn))` this will be always true, because you setted it one line before it...

Comment: You've right, fixed it!